# Python - change value form a dictionary and list mixture

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I was trying to find a way to replace a value from a complex dictionary which may contain array as value. An example is shown below

```
{
   "ip1": "172.16.1.54",
   "ip2": "172.16.1.100",
   "no": 6,
   "config": [
      {
         "num": 1,
         "sno": 1,
         "st_conf": [
            {
               "frames": 1000,
               "id": 1,
               "vid": 1000,
               "mc1": "00 00 00 00 00 01",
               "mc2": "00 00 00 00 00 02"
            },
            {
               "frames": 2000,
               "id": 3,
               "vid": 1300,
               "mc1": "00 00 00 00 00 11",
               "mc2": "00 00 00 00 00 12"
            },
         ]
      },
      {
         "port_no": 2,
         "sw_port_no": 2,
         "stream_config": [
            {
               "frames": 1000,
               "id": 1,
               "vid": 1000,
               "mc1": "00 00 00 00 00 02",
               "mc1": "00 00 00 00 00 01"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

I wrote a function as below to modify a value in some path (say `port_config/0/st_conf/0/id`) as below

```
def set_data_in_path(self, path, data):
    tokens = path.split("/")
    tmp_conf = self._def_conf
    for token in tokens:
        if self.is_int(token):
            token = int(token)
        tmp_conf = tmp_conf[token]
    tmp_conf = data
```

But this function is not working. Can any one help me? 
What is the problem with my code and how I can resolve it. Because I don't have much experience in python.

Comment: I think the problem is, the tmp_conf is not reference to the variable

Comment: What is `self.is_int`?

Comment: to check if the key is int or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By eventually assigning `tmp_conf` a scalar value you lose the reference to the data structure, and the value of `data` you then assign to `tmp_conf` will not be reflected to the original data structure.

You should keep `tmp_conf` from reaching the node specified by the last token, and assign `data` to `tmp_conf` indexed by the last token instead:

```
def set_data_in_path(self, path, data):
    tokens = path.split("/")
    tmp_conf = self._def_conf
    for token in tokens[:-1]:
        if self.is_int(token):
            token = int(token)
        tmp_conf = tmp_conf[token]
    tmp_conf[tokens[-1]] = data
```